# SMTP TLS certificate

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I'm having some problems understanding how TLS/SSL is working for email.

I have some questions.

1. In my development machine if I debug the following code fails the first time arround on the "sslSocket.startHandshake()" line, but if I try it again straight away it is working fine.

The error message that I'm getting is: "Remote host closed connection during handshake".

When I deploy the same code to our staging environment and send an email the code is working fine first time. 
Both the development and staging server are in the same network and both have no anti virus programs runnning.

The only thing that I can think of as to why it is not working the first time around in the development environment is because I'm stepping through the code with the debugger and it's slower because of this.

Do you have any knowledge as to why I am receiving this error?

2. The code underneath is creating an SSL Socket. I'm curious to know if this code is enough for the connection with the mail server to be secure. Are these SSLSocketFactory classes dealing with certificates themselves?

2a) Or do I still need to specify a certificate somehow?

2b) Or is this code getting the certificate from the server and using the certificate to encrypt the data and send the encrypted data back and forth to the email server?

I know that it should work like it is described here:
RFC 3207 defines how SMTP connections can make use of encryption. Once a connection is established, the client issues a STARTTLS command. If the server accepts this, the client and the server negotiate an encryption mechanism. If the negotiation succeeds, the data that subsequently passes between them is encrypted.

2c) Is the code underneath doing this?

```
socket.setKeepAlive(true);

  SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(
          socket, 
          socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), 
          socket.getPort(),
          true);                 

  sslSocket.setUseClientMode(true);
  sslSocket.setEnableSessionCreation(true);
  sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"SSLv3", "TLSv1"});
  sslSocket.setKeepAlive(true);

  // Force handshake. This can throw!
  sslSocket.startHandshake();       

  socket = sslSocket;

  in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. In my development machine if I debug the following code fails the first time arround on the "sslSocket.startHandshake()" line, but if I try it again straight away it is working fine.
>      The error message that I'm getting is: "Remote host closed connection during handshake". []
>      The only thing that I can think of as to why it is not working the first time around in the development environment is because I'm stepping through the code with the debugger and it's slower because of this.

If you just do `startHandshake()` again with the underlying socket closed it should never work. If you go back to doing the TCP connection (e.g. `new Socket(host,port)`) and the initial SMTP exchange and STARTTLS, then yes I would expect it to avoid whatever problem affected the previous connection.

Yes, the server timing out because of the delay while you were debugging is quite possible, but to be certain you need to check logs on the server(s).

> 2. The code underneath is creating an SSL Socket. I'm curious to know if this code is enough for the connection with the mail server to be secure. Are these SSLSocketFactory classes dealing with certificates themselves?

Indirectly, yes. `SSLSocketFactory` creates an `SSLSocket` linked to an `SSLContext` which includes a `TrustManager` which is normally loaded from a truststore file. Your code defaults to the default `SSLContext` which has a `TrustManager` loaded from the default truststore, which is the file `jssecacerts` if present and otherwise `cacerts` in the `lib/security` directory in the JRE you are running. If your JRE hasn't been modified (by you or anyone else authorized on your system), depending on your variant or packaging of Java the installed JRE usually has no `jssecacerts` and contains or links to a `cacerts` file that (initially) contains root certs for about a hundred 'well-known' or established certificate authorities like Symantec, GoDaddy, Comodo, etc.

> 2a) Or do I still need to specify a certificate somehow?

Since when the handshake is done it is successful, obviously not.

> 2b) Or is this code getting the certificate from the server and using the certificate to encrypt the data and send the encrypted data back and forth to the email server?

Kind of/sort of/not quite. With some exceptions not applicable here, in an SSL/TLS handshake the server always provides its own certificate and usually intermediate or 'chain' certificates that link its cert to a trusted root cert (such as the abovementioned Symantec etc). The server cert is always used to authenticate the server, and sometimes alone but often combined with other mechanisms (particularly Diffie-Hellman ephemeral DHE or its elliptic-curve variant ECDHE) used to establish a set of several symmetric key values which are then used to encrypt and authenticate the data in both directions. For a more complete explanation see the canonical question and (multi-part!) answer in security.SX https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/

> 2c) Is the code underneath doing this?

It is starting an SSLv3 or TLSv1 client-side session on an existing socket. I'm not sure what other question you have here.

You might be better off leaving out the `setEnabledProtocols()`. Sun/Oracle Java version 8, which is the only one now supported, supports TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 by default. 1.1 and especially 1.2 are definitely better than 1.0, and should definitely be offered so that if the server supports them they get used. (Sun/Oracle 7 is more problematic; it *implements* 1.1 and 1.2, but does not *enable* them client side by default. There I would look at `.getSupportedProtocols` and if 1.1 and 1.2 are supported but not enabled I would add enable them. But if possible I would just upgrade to 8. Other versions of Java, notably IBM, differ significantly in crypto details.)

**SSLv3 should not be offered unless absolutely necessary**; it is now badly broken by POODLE (search on security.SX for dozens of Qs about POODLE). I would try without it, and only if the server insists on it re-enable it temporarily, _along with TLS 1.0 through 1.2 whenever possible, and simultaneously urge the server to upgrade so I can remove it again.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this really detailed explanation – it is extremely helpful.
For point 1, the underlying socket is open but closes when the transaction fails, or after it succeeds. So I don't think this impacts the second attempt, as that is an entirely new socket.

Comment: Also thank you for the tip to remove the setEnabledProtocols() function. I’m working with Java 8, so I have removed it. In the next couple of months I will create an email server and then I can more easily see what the server side is doing so I can determine what goes wrong with the handshake first time around. Funnily enough the code is working on our staging environment first time. 
Once again, thank you for your help!